# "Save" function doesn't work in a Simulink FMU

Tags: simulink, fmi

I'm creating a Simulink FMU for robot trajectories. I'm using MATLAB R2022a.

The input of my FMU is `targetPos`, i.e., the target point coordinates (x,y,z) of the robot. The outputs are:

- `ExitFlag` - (not) reachable point
- `config` - joint angles of the manipulator
- `info` - IK solver details

I'm aiming to save the joint angles of all waypoints in the trajectory, i.e., `config` in all Simulink iterations. I prefer to do it in .csv for later compatibility, but .mat is also fine. I've included the Save block in Simulink directly connected to `config`.
I've exported the model as standalone FMU and it's generated successfully.

Check the Simulink model and traceback when saving as FMU in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUQFs.png).

Then, I've tested the FMU in ROS 2 with the [fmi_adapter](https://github.com/boschresearch/fmi_adapter), but the .mat is not being generated.

```
ros2 launch fmi_adapter fmi_adapter_node.launch.py fmu_path:=FMI/Trajectory/RobotMARA_SimulinkFMU_v3.fmu
```

So, is there an incompatibility with the "Save" block in an FMU? Any work around to solve this problem is welcome.

Thank you,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file system is not defined in the FMI API, see https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/issues/326

Is it possible to define local variables or output that you can access from the the importing tool via the FMI API?

In FMI 3.0 you could define a binary stream to output your data.